# How do I Read and Display related data in asp.net mvc-core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

As a sample that I can build on, I want to use `Teams.ClubNo` to find `Club.ClubNo` and add `Club.ClubName` to the Teams Index page.

Sounds simple but I haven't found anything that works yet.

The filter (which I like) is confusing what I need to do in the controller.
No direct navigation exists in the database. Am using EF 2.1

Part of _context.Club and _context.Teams

```
public partial class Club
{
    public Club()
    public short ClubNo { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
}

public partial class Teams
{
    public Teams()
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public short HomeGround { get; set; }
    public short ClubNo { get; set; }
}
```

Part of my TeamsController.cs to display my Index page.

```
public class TeamsController : Controller
{
    private readonly SSFA_SQLContext _context;

    public TeamsController(SSFA_SQLContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Teams
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string filter, string filter1, string filter2, int page = 1, string sortExpression = "Division")
    {
        var qry = _context.Teams.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            { qry = qry.Where(p => p.Division.Contains(filter)); }

        var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(qry, 15, page, sortExpression, "Division");
        model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary  { "filter", filter } ;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Part of my Teams Index page.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Division)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Grade)
        </td>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClubNo)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Division)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClubNo)
            </td>
```

Comment: Share us what `PagingList` is.

Comment: For Paging see: https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2017/paging-in-asp-net-core-mvc-and-entityframework-core and https://www.nuget.org/packages/ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 documents were very helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

This is intended as a sample upon which to build other requirements of Related Data.

Part of my Models for Club.cs , Ground.cs and Teams.cs

```
public partial class Club
{
    public Club()
    public short ClubNo { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}

public partial class Ground
{
    public Ground()
    public short GroundNo { get; set; }
    public string GroundName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public partial class Teams
{
    public Teams()
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public short HomeGround { get; set; }
    public short ClubNo { get; set; }
}
```

Part of my TeamsController.cs to display my Index page.
public class TeamsController : Controller
{
    private readonly SSFA_SQLContext _context;

```
public TeamsController(SSFA_SQLContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

// GET: Teams
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string filter, int page = 1, string sortExpression = "Division")
{
    var qry = _context.Teams
        .AsNoTracking()
        .AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
        { qry = qry.Where(p => p.Division.Contains(filter)); }

    var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(qry, 15, page, sortExpression, "Division");
    model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary  { "filter", filter } ;

    return View(model);
}
```

**Object is to display ClubName and GroundName on Teams Index page**.

**Solution: (Most probably one of many possible ways to do it).**

Add following to Teams context.cs file: (No change is required to Club or Ground context files)

```
 entity.HasOne(q => q.ClubNavigation);
 entity.HasOne(q => q.GroundNavigation);
```

Add following to Teams.cs model file: (No change is required to Club or Ground model files)

```
public Club ClubNavigation { get; set; }
public Ground GroundNavigation { get; set; }
```

Add [ForeignKey("GroundNavigation")] above

```
public short HomeGround { get; set; }
```

(This one is required as HomeGround has to find GroundNo)

Add [ForeignKey("ClubNavigation")] above

```
public short ClubNo { get; set; }
```

As ClubNo is same in both files the second foreign key is not necessary but I think it is nice to have for consistency.

In TeamsController.cs change

```
var qry = _context.Teams
            .AsNoTracking()
            .AsQueryable();
```

To

```
var qry = _context.Teams
            .Include(q => q.ClubNavigation)
            .Include(q => q.GroundNavigation)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .AsQueryable();
```

Add following to Teams Index file:

```
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HomeGround)</th>
<td><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroundNavigation.GroundName)</b></td>
<th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClubNo)</th>
<td><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClubNavigation.ClubName)</b></td>
```

And

```
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HomeGround)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GroundNavigation.GroundName)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClubNo)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClubNavigation.ClubName)</td>
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you Tao for pushing me along.

Comment: Small mistake:                                                        <td><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroundNavigation.GroundName)</b></td>                                should be                                                                       <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GroundNavigation.GroundName)</th> (<b> not needed)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no `navigation property` between `Club` and `Teams`, you need to query the `ClubName` based on `ClubNo`. And since there is no `ClubName` in `Teams`, you need to define a new model which contains `Clubname`.

TeamsVM.cs

```
public partial class TeamsVM
{
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
    public string ClubName { get; set; }
}
```

And change query like below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index1(string filter, string filter1, string filter2, int page = 1, string sortExpression = "Division")
{
    var qry = _applicationDbContext.Teams.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
    { qry = qry.Where(p => p.Division.Contains(filter)); }
    var result = qry.Select(q => new TeamsVM
    {
        Division = q.Division,
        Grade = q.Grade,
        ClubName = _applicationDbContext.Club.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClubNo == q.ClubNo).ClubName
    });
    var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(result, 15, page, sortExpression, "Division");
    model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary { "filter", filter };
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: This sounds very clunky to me. There must be a better way. I may have half a dozen fields like this on the one Index page. If it was a form I would have something like =DLookUp("[ClubName]","[Club]","[ClubNo]=Form![ClubNo]"). If it was a query I would have something like Select Club.ClubName from Club where Teams.ClubNo = Club.ClubNo. Surely there is a simpler way to do this sort of thing in mvc-core.

Comment: @Rod If so, you need to change your current design. For View, you need to make the `ClubName` control as select control. For query, you will need to change to linq query. In my option, you could consider change your model deisgn with navigation properties, and used `AutoMapper` to achieve converting Entity Model to ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Tao. Still sounds way too complex to me. I will try a few other things first like .Include or ViewBag etc and see what I can get to work.

Comment: @Rod Before using Include, your model need to have navigate properties.

Comment: Thanks Tao, you are persistent so will ask .. how do I add navigation property. Can I just add annotation to Teams.cs as [ForeignKey("ClubNo")]  
        public short ClubNo { get; set; }

Comment: or do I have to change my context file in some way ? and what does TeamsController.cs become: does it look something like var qry = _context.Teams.Include(e => e.ClubNo)AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

Comment: @Rod check this doc [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: Thanks Tao, found that article yesterday, was useful. Nearly there:

Added   public Club ClubNavigation { get; set; }    to Teams.cs 
Added   entity.HasOne(q => q.ClubNavigation);       to my _context.cs
Added   .Include(q => q.ClubNavigation)             to my controller.cs qry
Added   <td><b>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ClubNavigation.ClubName)</b></td>  (needed bold for heading ??)
and     <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClubNavigation.ClubName)</td>    to my Index page    and it works.

Comment: Small problem still : Have similar situation with Ground, tried the same thing but am getting an error on page display:
Invalid column name 'GroundNavigationGroundNo'. 
Only difference I can see is that for Teams to Club both contain ClubNo (key in Club) as fields. 
For Teams to Ground it is HomeGround to GroundNo (as key). 

How do I equate the names ?

Comment: @Rod Share us your current model defination and controller code.

Comment: My problem was to do with Foreign Keys and how to use them. All working now. Will post an answer shortly.